# How to insert new database column/field with least pain in yii2

Tags: database, yii2

I am having trouble in generating CRUDs again and again and losing my previous work. Tell me any other way to change the database fields.Thanks

Comment: Are you using migrations? There is no *need* for you to regenerate your CRUD if you are only adding database columns. If you add a column to any table your previous work will still work. If you want to use that field you will need to add it to the model and then use it, as needed, on the views. You should also consider, if you find yourself updating your database frequently, if the design is appropriate, it might be that your initial design wasn't that good, in that case it might be worth studying the requirements again and redesigning the database from scratch.

Comment: Use keyboard and fingers. Generating CRUD is one time action if you changed something in generated files, then you have to add manually additional fields.

Comment: @RaulSauco actually i m new to this, now i have searched things and now using migrations its working, if there is problem or issue again i will ask you again. thanks a lot.

Comment: @RaulSauco i am using migration, but changes in model class are not done accordingly, what to do now!!

Comment: @jaff one question. What would the developers be for if code could write by itself?

Comment: @yupik i appreciate it dude, but i am using yii framework for ease and i expect it to change the required things whenever i use migration. i am not running away from the code but expect some fast things from yii

Comment: @jaff right now you missmatched framework with auto-coding robot. It's not a tool to auto-update your code, same as migration is not designed for it. You can't just make everything by clicking. And yii have alot of fast things, have alot out of box features, but it's not auto-coding program.

Comment: @jaff  .. when you use migration  .. the change are not directly refletec to the model .(with migration there is not a code generator as for gii)  in this case . you must adapt  the related  model  . for rules  (data type , length ,, and or safe) .. and label .. and also in modelSearch for filter and sort  .. otherwise  .. if you have not coded  additional features you could delete  teh code generated by gii  and recreate as new .. (model, controller and view)

Comment: for such kind of things i usually extend the model from the base model and whenever i have a change in database table field I just override the base model and add the changes necessary to the extended model that way i keep my changes intact.